# \usepackage{hyperref} causing incomplete \iffalse error

Tags: hyperref

I'm working on my thesis and I'm having a hard time getting the `hyperref` package to work. I've included it as the last `\usepackage` but when I add that line it gives a weird error.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Images/}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{url}
\providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[byname]{smartref}
%\usepackage{hyperref} %comment out for hardcopy
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{rotating} % <-- HERE

\usepackage{glossaries}
%I put it here
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Now I didn't do anything other than add that line. I didn't download it or anything, but I haven't downloaded any of the packages I'm using specially, they've all just worked, so maybe I'm missing something that isn't standard? This isn't a full set of my code but my thesis code is huge, even without the inserted chapters, so I'd rather not post it all. When I add the `hyperref` package I get this error

```
!Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 386
<inserted text>
\fi
The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
! Emergency stop
```

But I don't have any `\if` in my document.

Also just for reference, lines 377-389 (since it reports a problem with line 386):

```
\begin{preliminary}

%% This generates the title page from the information given above.

\maketitle
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Certificate of Examination}
%\makecert %%%JENNA COMMENTED OUT
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Co-Authorship Statement}
\coauthor{\makecoauthor}  %comment this out if none
%\newpage
%%%JENNA ADDED THIS ALL
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
\newpage
```

Comment: `glossaries` is one of the few packages that should be loaded *after* `hyperref`.

Comment: I tried putting it right before glossaries and still got same error

Comment: Please consider posting a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), to help us help you.  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Did you mean to load `hyperref` twice?  I don't know if it's related, but it appears that at some point `hyperref` was included and commented out *before* you added yours.  Any idea if both were ever loaded at once?

Comment: Try deleting the aux file.  Adding hyperref changes the number of arguments required for some of the macros.

Comment: Where is `preliminary` defined?

Comment: try using different fonts (not txfonts).